# Pardot: Form Handler answers with error instead of redirecting to success location

Tags: pardot

When using a Form Handler with a form on our website, I get the following response, after sending the form:

> This is a form handler page with no content. Use the form's direct URL instead.

The page also responds with a http status 400: Bad request.

I have no forms, and never planned on using forms. I have tested the formhandlers before, but now they don't work anymore.

The form handler is set up wit a success and an error page, data forwarding, three form fields, of which one is required.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found it out: my form had the wrong `enctype`.

Pardot accepts either no `enctype` or an `enctype` of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. An `enctype` of `multipart/form-data` isn't accepted and results in the behaviour I mentioned in my question.

[Source](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000264418&language=en_US&type=1)